# Liquibase External Authenticator Caching for Snowflake

Tags: liquibase

How can you cache external authenticator in liquibase for Snowflake? The idea being you only need to login via SSO once and it will cache your login token for the next request.

I'm familiar with the additional module in the python connector that allows you do this, but I'm not sure if there is a built in way with JDBC.